# Subplots size/tick spacing pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have searched for similar problems and not found any, so I apologize.

I have this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

yearlymean_gm = np.load('ts_globalmean_annualmean.npz')
ts = yearlymean_gm['ts_aqct']

time = np.arange(0., 45 , 1)
plt.figure( figsize=(12, 5), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k' )

ax = plt.subplot(3, 4, 1)

data = ts[0, :]
plt.plot(time, data)
plt.title('Annual Mean Global Mean Temperature', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('year', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel(modnames[0], fontsize=12)
plt.xlim(0, 50), plt.ylim(275, 310)
ax.set_xticks(time)
ax.set_xticklabels(time, fontsize = 8)

ax= plt.subplot(3, 4, 2)

data = ts[1, :]
plt.plot(time, data)
plt.title('Annual Mean Global Mean Temperature', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('year', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel(modnames[1], fontsize=12)
plt.xlim(0, 50), plt.ylim(275, 310)
ax.set_xticks(time)


ax = plt.subplot(3, 4, 3)

data = ts[2, :]
plt.plot(time, data)
plt.title('Annual Mean Global Mean Temperature', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('year', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel(modnames[2], fontsize=12)
plt.xlim(0, 50), plt.ylim(275, 310)
ax.set_xticks(time)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.close
```

There are currently 9 missing plots, as I'm sure you could guess, [image: Here's what it's spitting out right now]

Here are the three issues, to be clear:
1) Each subplot is *tiny* compared to the size of the figure (and, you know... what's easily visible). Reducing the size of the figure doesn't make the subplots any more easily readable.

2) They are too close together. I have some ideas about how to solve this, but I feel like I need to resolve 1) first.

3) The axes are so small that the xticks appear all bunched up

I've searched and found no explanation as to how to do this that's written at a level I can understand. The pyplot documentation is essentially gibberish to me.

Thanks in advance for any assistance (and if anyone can offer more general advice about what I'm doing in addition to specific advice about solving this problem, I would appreciate the edification).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so several things are happening here.  Let's go through them one at a time.  After you instantiate the plot, you call `ax = plt.subplot(3, 4, _)` 3 times.  However, `.subplot(3,4,_)` breaks the plot into 3 rows and 4 columns and the underscore selects which piece of this grid to select starting with 1 (instead of 0).  We can number them with the following code:

```
plt.figure( figsize=(12, 5), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k' )
for N in range(1,13):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 4, N)
    ax.annotate(s=str(N), xy=(.4,.4), fontsize=16)
```

[image]

So but using `.subplot(3, 4, 1)`, `.subplot(3, 4, 2)`, and `.subplot(3, 4, 3)` you are only selecting the first 3 of the 12 sections.

When you add the data to the plot, `ax.set_xticks(time)` adds 45 ticks to the xaxis (which is quite a few), and `ax.set_xticklabels(time, fontsize = 8)` adds a label at each tick.  This is why it looks so crowded.  One options is to reduce the number of ticks, the other is to stretch the x-axis out.  Since you have 3 subplots, I think you wanted to 3 rows stacked vertically.

You don't need `plt.xlim(0, 50)` or `plt.ylim(275, 310)`. The axis will resize the plot limits for you, unless you have a specific reason for overriding them.

My recommendation would be to use `plt.subplots(3, 1)` (notice the extra "s") rather than repeated calls to `plt.subplot`.  What's the difference?  `plt.subplots(3,1)` returns a tuple of a `figure` object and an array of `axis` objects.  In this case it is a 1-D array because we only call for 1 column.  (NOTE: I created fake data for illustrative purposes.)

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,1, figsize=(12,5), dpi=80, facecolor='w',
                         edgecolor='k', sharex=True)  # sharex shares the x-axis

for i, ax in enumerate(axes):  # need to enumerate to slice the data
    data = ts[i, :]
    ax.plot(time, data)
    ax.set_ylabel(modnames[i], fontsize=12)
    ax.set_xticks(time)
    ax.set_xticklabels(time, fontsize = 8)

# set xlabel outside of for loop so only the last axis get an xlabel
ax.set_xlabel('year', fontsize=12)
fig.tight_layout()

# set the title, adjust the spacing
fig.suptitle('Annual Mean Global Mean Temperature', fontsize=14)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.90)
```

[image]